# ADODB Recordset fields access order gives empty values

Tags: sql-server, vba, ado

I got an SQL 2005 table with many (84 to be specific) fields (actually it is a query returned by a procedure)
It looks like when I access recordset fields placed later then some field placed earlier becomes empty while server had actually returned a value for it
Had anyone such problem?
My solution is to put such disappeared field at the end of a table so when it is accessed later by a code (here VBA) its value is still accessible BUT I see it as a big problem in ADODB.Recordset 2.8 as I should not care about field order
I know that question is not very specific but maybe someone had a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

One way to to make sure the field values are there is to pass on the recordset to a array like (You will have to build your own connection function):

```
Function getStoredProcedure() As Variant

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim values As Variant

Set conn = getConn("Server", "Database")
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedureName"
cmd.Parameters.Item("@TODAY") = today

Set rs = cmd.Execute
If Not rs.EOF Then
    values = rs.GetRows
Else
    Exit Function
End If

Set cmd = Nothing
getStoredProcedure= transposeArray(values)

End Function
```

From there you can always retrieve the values from the array. Otherwise, without seeing your code or understand what you are trying to do, I cannot tell if this is really an issue with ADODB because I cannot recreate this issue when pulling field items in any order I want such as: `rs.Fields.Item(i).Value` for i = any number in any order.

Comment: i know that GetRows can be used to overcome the issue but it makes using recordset more cumbersome :( I will try to prepare test sql/code to reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem twice. There are two exception fields in my query string. Running the query string in sql server, they can return the values but these two exception fields are empty when run the query string in VBA used recordset. I put these exception fields behind other normal fields in the query string, and then they can return value in the recordset instead of blank.  So it's really a big problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33193775)